# Problema para iniciar sesion con un usuario en SQL Shell

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, shell, sesiones, cuenta-usuario

estoy empezando a estudiar programación, he creado el usuario correctamente en SQL Shell, pero segun mi libro me indica que debo salir de la sesión y volver a entrar con esta orden: template1= /q.

Intento hacerlo pero lo unico que cambia es que en vez de un "=" despues del 1, aparece un
"-".

Despues el propio libro me indica que ponga esta orden:

`$psql -U (nombre del usuario) -d template1`

Como al cerrar sesion con "/q", se queda el template no puedo escribir la siguiente orden
alguien sabe como podria solucionarlo (seguro es error mio, hace nada que me he iniciado y no tengo casi ningun conocimiento todavia,

Gracias